# Read space on fscanf

Tags: c, scanf

I have a field that allows whitespace in my text file that is 'citepage'. Is it possible for `fscanf` to read the field with blanks between tabs and then show it in `printf`? The citepage is getting data of timestamp.

Exemple .txt:

```
1[tab]AAAI[tab]Low-cost Outdoor Robot Platform for the Penn State Abington Mini Grand Challenge[tab]2005[tab]Robert Avanzato[tab]1[tab][espaco][tab]2013-03-07 16:49:1
```

My current code:

```
while (!feof(fp)){
    fscanf(fp,"%d\t %19[^\t]\t %300[^\t]\t %d\t %100[^\t]\t %d\t %s\t %19[^\t]\n  ",&artigos.id,artigos.sigla,artigos.titulo,&artigos.ano,artigos.autores,&artigos.citacoes,artigos.citepage,artigos.timestamp);        
    printf("\nid: %d ",artigos.id);
    printf("\nsigla: %s ",artigos.sigla);
    printf("\ntitulo: %s ",artigos.titulo);
    printf("\nano: %d ",artigos.ano);
    printf("\nautores: %s ",artigos.autores);
    printf("\ncitacoes: %d ",artigos.citacoes);
    printf("\ncitepage: %s ",artigos.citepage);
    printf("\ntimestamp: %s ",artigos.timestamp);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`fscanf` is not good for separting things based on tabs or newlines as opposed to spaces, because it treats all whitespace as the same -- something to be skipped and ignored.  Whenever you have a whitespace character in your format string (doesn't matter if it'a a space or tab or newline; they all do the same thing), fscanf will read and throw away whitespace until it finds a non-whitespace character.  So in your case, when it gets to the `\t` after the `%d` that read the `citacoes`, it will skip the following
`\t \t` in the input, and the next character to be read will be `2`, so that's where it will start reading for `citepage`.

Now you can use `%*1[\t]` in the format string to skip a single tab character (rather than all whitespace), but doing so is messy and error prone.  It also gets easily confused by incorrect input, making it almost impossible to give the user proper diagnostics about malformed input.  But if you want to do that, replace all the tabs in the format string with `%*1[\t]` and remove all the spaces and it should work.

A much better choice would be to read the entire line into a buffer (with fgets) and then use `strsep` to split it up on the tab characters.

Also you should never use `feof` -- it doesn't return true until *after* you've tried unsuccessfully to read past the end of the file.  Always check the return value of the fscanf or fgets call instead.

Comment: Is `strsep` portable?

Answer (score 0):

The `'\t'` and `' '` directives do the same thing: skip any white-space.  To use a tab as a separator in `scanf()`, one needs to use `"%*1[\t]"`.  `strtok()` or a simple loop may be easier.  See @Chris Dodd

Suggest `fgets()/sscanf()` for better error handling especially for this complex scan.
Further, the format specifier for `artigos.citepage` needs adjustment.

```
char buf[200];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp) == NULL) Handle_EOFIOError();

// scan, but do not save 1 `\t`
#define TF   "*1[\t]"
if (8 == sscanf(buf,
    "%d"        TF "%19[^\t]" TF "%300[^\t]" TF "%d" TF
    "%100[^\t]" TF "%d"       TF "%19[^\t]"  TF "%19[^\t]",
    &artigos.id, artigos.sigla, artigos.titulo, &artigos.ano, 
    artigos.autores, &artigos.citacoes, artigos.citepage, artigos.timestamp) {
  Success();
}
```